# Bundle install in Vagrant timing out. Apparently not fixed by turning off natdns

Tags: dns, bundler, virtualbox, vagrant, nat

I'm trying to set up a Vagrant/Virtualbox VM on an OS X Mavericks machine to do some Rails development, and all of my attempts at running `bundle install` are timing out.

I've had this problem before, and was able to resolve it by turning off natdnsproxy1 and natdnshostresolver1 in Vagrantfile. I looked up what seem to be the current instructions for doing that, and changed my Vagrantfile to read as follows (minus all the comments, of course)...

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ffuenf/debian-7.4.0-amd64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "off"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "off"]
  end
end
```

I fully expected that to fix the problem for me, but `bundle install` is still timing out during fetching.

Any ideas?

Comment: See your VM's `/etc/resolv.conf`, if the VM can reach 8.8.8.8 just manually change it to use 8.8.8.8, this is a quick and dirty fix.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that DNS was not the problem at all. I had outdated sources in Gemfile (such as http://rubygems.org), and when I replaced those with just `source 'https://rubygems.org'`, the problem went away.